# When I try to execute project with React native I get the following problem

Tags: android, react-native

I have all the environment variables configured correctly, and I have this error

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
82 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 79 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Proyectos\Personales\meissaa-app-mad\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\appcompat'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Proyectos\Personales\meissaa-app-mad\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\appcompat'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Proyectos\Personales\meissaa-app-mad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Proyectos\Personales\meissaa-app-mad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Proyectos\Personales\meissaa-app-mad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: I don't think the Android studio currently supports Gradle. Update Gradle or update your Android studio.

Comment: i'm facing with this issue too, @Antonio > have you find how to resolve it?